# Why does this de-duplication code not work when I chain it together?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select duplicates in this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'firstname':['stack','Bar Bar',np.nan,'Bar Bar','john','mary','jim'],
                   'lastname':['jim','Bar','Foo Bar','Bar','con','sullivan','Ryan'],
                   'email':[np.nan,'Bar','Foo Bar','Bar','john@com','mary@com','Jim@com']})

print(df)

  firstname  lastname     email
0     stack       jim       NaN
1   Bar Bar       Bar       Bar
2       NaN   Foo Bar   Foo Bar
3   Bar Bar       Bar       Bar
4      john       con  john@com
5      mary  sullivan  mary@com
6       jim      Ryan   Jim@com
```

This method seems to work fine:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'])

df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'], keep=False)]

print(df)

  firstname lastname email
1   Bar Bar      Bar   Bar
3   Bar Bar      Bar   Bar
```

Whereas if I chain the operations, it doesn't work:

```
dupes = (df.dropna(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'])
                 .duplicated(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'], keep=False))

df = df[dupes]

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

Should I generally stay away from chaining like this and just keep it simple? What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This si expected.

Problem in second solution is filter with already filtered values, so output index is different like original index, so raised error.

```
print(df)
  firstname  lastname     email
0     stack       jim       NaN
1   Bar Bar       Bar       Bar
2       NaN   Foo Bar   Foo Bar
3   Bar Bar       Bar       Bar
4      john       con  john@com
5      mary  sullivan  mary@com
6       jim      Ryan   Jim@com

dupes = (df.dropna(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'])
                 .duplicated(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'], keep=False))

print(dupes)
1     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool
```

In first sample you filter with already filtered data, so index same and working nice:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'])
print(df)
  firstname  lastname     email
1   Bar Bar       Bar       Bar
3   Bar Bar       Bar       Bar
4      john       con  john@com
5      mary  sullivan  mary@com
6       jim      Ryan   Jim@com

print(df.duplicated(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'], keep=False))
1     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool


df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'], keep=False)]
print(df)
  firstname lastname email
1   Bar Bar      Bar   Bar
3   Bar Bar      Bar   Bar
```

Possible solution is use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
dupes1 = dupes.reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)
print(dupes1)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool

dupes1 = dupes.reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)

df = df[dupes1]
print(df)
  firstname lastname email
1   Bar Bar      Bar   Bar
3   Bar Bar      Bar   Bar
```

Comment: Thanks, that reindex tip is very handy.

Answer (score 1):

With your first example you updated the dataframe by assigning it, if you print it after the drop na you can see that the index changed:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'])
print(df)

    firstname  lastname     email
1   Bar Bar       Bar       Bar
3   Bar Bar       Bar       Bar
4      john       con  john@com
5      mary  sullivan  mary@com
6       jim      Ryan   Jim@com
```

The problem with the chained operations is that you didn't change the index of your dataframe, but your dupes Series has less rows.

```
dupes =  df.dropna(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email']).duplicated(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'], keep=False)
print(dupes)
print(df)

1     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool

  firstname  lastname     email
0     stack       jim       NaN
1   Bar Bar       Bar       Bar
2       NaN   Foo Bar   Foo Bar
3   Bar Bar       Bar       Bar
4      john       con  john@com
5      mary  sullivan  mary@com
6       jim      Ryan   Jim@com
```

When you try to get the rows from the Dataframe by indexing using the dupes Series, the error is raised because the index don't match.